# How to use a result object from Jpa repository save() later in the same method that invoked save()?

Tags: java, spring

In my controller I invoke a method from a service that will invoke save() on my database, and return me the object that was saved. That class that I am saving has a auto_generated id, so when i save it to the database, i expect to be returned with the id set (and that is working fine). In the same controller i store a result of that save() in a variable, and I found out that it's id is not set. That is because save() will actually save i to the database once that transaction is completed (when i exit the controller method. My problem is that i want to use that result before i exit my controller in a different service. How can I force the service (and consenquetly the repositroy) to save it immidiatelly and return me the result.

The reason for using id of classA in classB , is because classB is a "conncetion" table between two tables in database, and I should update it only when certain conditions are met, but this is of the point. I have already tried saveAndFlush() method in repository, that this service is calling, but it doesn't help. My service is only doing calling a save(), or saveAndFlush() method and nothing else (so it can't be a problem in the service).

I have already tried @Transactional annotation with REQUIRES_NEW, but it isn't working.

```
@PostMapping("")
public ClassA createClassA(@RequestBody ClassA classA){
   ClassA a = classAService.saveClassA (classA);
   System.out.println("Id = " + a.getIdClassA());
   classBService.saveClassB(new classB(a.getId()); //it will cause an exception if a.getId() returns 0

   return classA;
}
```

System.out.println will print out Id=0, but should print out Id=(some number that database makes, and cannot be zero because database has AUTO INCREMENT)

I have already tested all other services, repositories, connections etc. I am just interested how to force a response to come immidatelly so it can be stored in a variable and used later in the method.

Comment: First, the fact that ClassB needs the ID of a rather than just `a` itself is suspicious: you should not store IDs, byt ManyToOne associations. But all you should need is a flush(). The ID is not generated when the transaction commits. It's generated when the entity is written to the table, i.e. at flush time.

Comment: try saveAndFlush

Comment: Btw, what's the method you used to generate a id automatically?

Comment: Id is generated in the database when classA is submited. I achieved that through "AUTO INCREMENT".

Comment: @MarkoŠego that will make the database generate an ID. That won't tell JPA that the ID is autogenerated.

Comment: `That is because save() will actually save i to the database once that transaction is completed (when i exit the controller method.`

What does this mean? You start a tx and submit it is the scope of controller explicitly?

Comment: In my test, a id automatically generated by \@Id and @GeneratedValue will be instantly returned by save method(even not saveAndFlush). The transaction does effect when the insert sql is truly executed, while id generation is not effected.

Comment: @Lebecca it depends on the generation strategy. if you use sequence or table, the ID is generated when the entity is persisted, but if you use identity, the ID can only be generated by actually executing the insert query, so it's only available after a flush.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your guidance, I'ii try to explore deeply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thank you for the comments, @JBNizet and @Lebecca you were both right :). Indeed saveAndFlush() would reslove my problem if I had told my class that id will be generated in the database. Thats why the soultion is to put something like @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY), and to add saveAndFlush(). It worked after these two steps.